# COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-xxx : no such file or directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a github actions workflow to build a docker image:

```
name: Backend-Demo Docker Image CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Login to Azure Container Registry
        run: echo ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }} | docker login ${{ secrets.LOGIN_SERVER_URL }} -u ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME }} --password-stdin
      - name: Get the version
        id: vars
        run: echo ::set-output name=tag::$(echo ${GITHUB_REF:10})
      - name: Build the tagged Docker image
        run: docker build . --file backend/Dockerfile --tag backend-demo/spring-boot:v1.0
```

The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM openjdk:14-alpine
MAINTAINER example.com
RUN mkdir -p /opt/demo-0.0.1/lib
# Setting application source code working directory
WORKDIR /opt/demo-0.0.1/
COPY target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/demo-0.0.1/lib/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
# ADD target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/demo-0.0.1/lib/

RUN sh -c 'touch demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java"]
CMD ["-jar", "/opt/demo-0.0.1/lib/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

But when I execute this workflow I got this error at the `COPY` instruction:

```
Step 5/8 : COPY target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/demo-0.0.1/lib/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder851513197/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar: no such file or directory
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I have been checking and it looks a typical error when the file we have the `Dockerfile` in a different directory like my instruction:

`docker build . --file backend/Dockerfile --tag backend-demo/spring-boot:v1.0`

I also don't have `.dockerignore` file and my Dockerfile is called `Dockerfile` precisely.

The `target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` file I am trying to copy is present in my github repository
Not sure what could be happening with the context, but probably [this answer](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/90#issuecomment-509810005) could be a good hint?

Comment: is `Dockerfile` in same level as `target/` directory in your file tree? you can also try with relative path like `COPY ./target/demo-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ...`

Comment: @oli Yes, `Dockerfile` is at the same level as `target` directory. I also tried with relative PATH at `COPY` without success.

Comment: As a debugging step you can add `RUN ls -l` above `COPY` instruction to see the contents of directory inside image.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you run

```sh
docker build . --file backend/Dockerfile ...
```

The path argument `.` becomes the *context directory*.  (Docker actually sends itself a copy of this directory tree, which is where the `/var/lib/docker/tmp/...` path comes from.)  The source arguments of `COPY` and `ADD` instructions are relative to the context directory, not relative to the Dockerfile.

If your source tree looks like

```
.
+-- backend
| \-- Dockerfile
\-- target
  \-- demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

that matches the Dockerfile you show.  But if instead you have

```
.
+-- backend
  +-- Dockerfile
  \-- target
    \-- demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

you'll get the error you see.

If you don't need to refer to anything outside of the context directory, you can just change what directory you're passing to `docker build`

```sh
COPY target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/demo-0.0.1/lib/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

```sh
docker build backend ...
```

Or, if you do have other content you need to copy in, you need to change the `COPY` paths to be relative to the topmost directory.

```sh
COPY backend/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/demo-0.0.1/lib/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
COPY common/config/demo.yml /opt/demo-0.0.1/etc/demo.yml
```

```sh
docker build . -f backend/Dockerfile ...
```

Answer (score 1):

WORKDIR just tells you from where the other commands will be executed.An important point is WORKDIR works w.r.t docker directory,not to local/git directory.As per your example, WORDIR does not take context to **/opt/demo-0.0.1/** , but just creates an empty directory as **/opt/demo-0.0.1/** inside the docker. In order to make dockerfile work, you should give full path in COPY command as **COPY /opt/demo-0.0.1/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/demo-0.0.1/lib/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar**.Make sure Dockerfile is at the same level as /opt directory.

Comment: Got it about `WORKDIR` I think the empty directory `/opt/demo-0.0.1/` is created. I don't understand about giving full path at `COPY` command because is not supposed that the `src path` at `COPY` is my file system? I mean I don't have /opt/demo-0-0.1 path in my filesystem. Could you elaborate a little bit more about your answer please?

Comment: When you run COPY <src> <dest>, src is w.r.t git repo, so here the context will always be the directory where dockerfile is present, and this context does not change by WORKDIR. So, src should should always contain the full path of the file which we want to copy. And <dest> is set w.r.t to docker container, whose default context is root but can be changed with WORKDIR. New directory will be created if WORKDIR does not exist as above. So <dest> as  /opt/demo-0.0.1/lib/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar is equal to 
WORKDIR /opt/demo-0.0.1/  and 
COPY src lib/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: Could you check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/bgarcial/8467897824971bf43070b97fb0682281#file-dockerfile-L8), please? it is my `Dockerfile` now, but not sure if the `WORKDIR` instruction should be before or after `COPY`

Comment: Since you're using an absolute path as the destination for the `COPY`, it doesn't matter what you set the `WORKDIR` to.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to build the image without running maven install before, my Dockerfile was like:

```
FROM amazoncorretto:11

COPY ./target/*.jar /application.jar

CMD ["application.jar"]
```

And it was failing on the second step (COPY...) because target did not exist, because I did not build the jar before with for example maven install command, so first make sure target exist and contains the latest jar